# Save and Delete markers using Google map API V3

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I got a trouble using GMAP V3, when I realized that I need to save the changes in the map in a database, I found no way to do that. Before start to workaround I would like to listen some ideas firsrt.. and there no better place to do this, the comunnity stackoverflow always gave me great ideas to solve the problems and I m sure that will not be different.

Well,

I have a script to mesure the elevation of a region and I have also pointed something by hand in my own code, follow the example:

```
  var examples = [{
    latlngs: [
      [-24.116537, -49.358257],
      [-24.123348, -49.344267],
      [-24.122409, -49.329212],
      [-24.116478, -49.306664],
      [-24.101001, -49.313376],
      [-24.095218, -49.333645]
    ],
    mapType: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    travelMode: 'direct'
    }, {
    latlngs: [
      [-23.991412, -48.894621],
      [-23.969345, -48.884353],
  [-23.973734, -48.855789],
  [-23.996274, -48.860673],
  [-24.00085, -48.886786]
    ]
    mapType: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    travelMode: 'direct'
   }];
```

**Then a initialize everything:**

```
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(15, 0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
```

**Now I have the function to add markers on the map**

```
// Add a marker and trigger recalculation of the path and elevation
  function addMarker(latlng, doQuery) {
    if (markers.length < 100) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
      })

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
        updateElevation();
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      if (doQuery) {
        updateElevation();
      }

      if (markers.length == 100) {
        document.getElementById('address').disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Apenas 100 pontos podem ser adicionados.");
    }
  }
```

'til here everything works fine, but I need to add some functionalities to the map.
I need to add a new marker and a save button to the map, 'cause I need the new changes go to my database.. I just want to know if there are some function in GMAP API, then I do not need to re-invent the wheel..

Another problem, I need to delete only one marker, I do already, but only to all markers, and now I need only one to delete.

I think in the function addMarker with var marker I can use to put the values in a database, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at your code and find ways to decouple these features. For instance you can wrap the google maps api and make it generic. For instance here is one that I wrote:

http://bobcravens.com/files/gmap3/0.1/jquery.gmap3.js

In this wrapper you can see an example of how to add/delete individual markers.

The other area to keep separate is your database interactions. These can be done using AJAX. Here, I recommend you pull in a library that normalizes the differences between browsers. I personally like jQuery for this. I would put all my database calls into a javascript object. Or at least put the db calls in the 'save' button event handler. The AJAX calls with jQuery look something like:

```
var data = {};
data.lat = 89.0;
data.lng = -10.0;
data.name = 'marker name';
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/1.0/markers/save.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    error: function(){
        alert('Error on ajax.');
    },
    success: function(data){
       alert('success...do other stuff here');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Hi @Bob thanks for the explanation, but I really prefer to decouple all features and try a workaround untill it works as I wish, I prefer because I do not understand very well Ajax, and probably I will mess up using it.. Anyway, congrats to your wrap, I had tried tu use, but it do not work to me, but I got the main idea ... I think it is the most important thing, now I will work on this, try to find a way to get things done as I wish. Thanks to clear everything. bye!

Comment: Are all the google maps api calls read-only? Is there an api call that allows writing to a user's map data? From what I can tell here (and on most search results on the topic), there's reading map data, displaying it in the client, overlaying new markers on the client view, and in this question saving to a local (or hosted) database that you have access to.